# How to have multiple add to home screen on same domain on android?

Tags: android, html-framework-7

I want to be able to add 3 different icons to the home screen on the same domain.

So one for each index file in the below. One for the startpage and one each for the subfolders.

```
index.html
manifest.json
/app/index.html
/app/appmanifest.json
/admin/index.html
/admin/adminmanifest.json
```

So as I have it now, it works to add all 3 if I start to add the 2 in the subfolders, but if I start with the top index, then I can´t add the ones in the subfolers, then it thinks it has already installed it.

And the manifest files looks like this.

```
{
  "name": "Testing",
  "short_name": "Testing",
  "start_url": "index.html",
  "display": "standalone",
  "icons": [
  {
    "src": "images/ikoner/192x192.png",
    "type": "image/png",
    "sizes": "192x192"
  },
  {
    "src": "images/ikoner/512x512.png",
    "type": "image/png",
    "sizes": "512x512"
  }
]
}
```

So why isn´t it working if I add the top one first?
I don´t know what Im missing, so any input appreciated, thanks.

Comment: which framework is this ? react native ?

Comment: Its a webapp build with framework7.io

Comment: is this the correct tag for it ?

Comment: Yes I guess it is.